# Does lubridate not like subsetting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, lubridate

This problem is associated with a question that I asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002213/questions-associated-with-error-aesthetics-must-be-either-length-1-or-the-same).
I have spent some time thinking about how to more clearly convey my problem and apologize for the wordy question.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Below is a heavily subsetted hundred line snippet of the dataset that I am working with.

```
    SPD_2015 <- structure(list(summarized.offense.description = c("ASSAULT", 
"THREATS", "CAR PROWL", "SHOPLIFTING", "MAIL THEFT", "THREATS", 
"DISTURBANCE", "STOLEN PROPERTY", "TRESPASS", "VEHICLE THEFT", 
"CAR PROWL", "THREATS", "STOLEN PROPERTY", "VEHICLE THEFT", "BURGLARY-SECURE PARKING-RES", 
"CAR PROWL", "THREATS", "BIKE THEFT", "BURGLARY", "ASSAULT", 
"STOLEN PROPERTY", "DISTURBANCE", "VEHICLE THEFT", "CAR PROWL", 
"OTHER PROPERTY", "ASSAULT", "PROPERTY DAMAGE", "BURGLARY-SECURE PARKING-RES", 
"ANIMAL COMPLAINT", "OTHER PROPERTY", "BURGLARY", "BURGLARY", 
"CAR PROWL", "SHOPLIFTING", "BURGLARY", "PROPERTY DAMAGE", "DISTURBANCE", 
"PROPERTY DAMAGE", "STOLEN PROPERTY", "OTHER PROPERTY", "MAIL THEFT", 
"PROPERTY DAMAGE", "VEHICLE THEFT", "OTHER PROPERTY", "ROBBERY", 
"CAR PROWL", "NARCOTICS", "OTHER PROPERTY", "BURGLARY", "DISTURBANCE", 
"ASSAULT", "BURGLARY-SECURE PARKING-RES", "OTHER PROPERTY", "FRAUD", 
"SHOPLIFTING", "OTHER PROPERTY", "OTHER PROPERTY", "DISTURBANCE", 
"CAR PROWL", "STOLEN PROPERTY", "OTHER PROPERTY", "OTHER PROPERTY", 
"VIOLATION OF COURT ORDER", "DISTURBANCE", "NARCOTICS", "ASSAULT", 
"DISTURBANCE", "TRESPASS", "NARCOTICS", "CAR PROWL", "NARCOTICS", 
"OTHER PROPERTY", "CAR PROWL", "CAR PROWL", "ASSAULT", "TRAFFIC", 
"OTHER PROPERTY", "CAR PROWL", "PROSTITUTION", "OTHER PROPERTY", 
"OTHER PROPERTY", "ASSAULT", "BURGLARY", "DISTURBANCE", "PROPERTY DAMAGE", 
"PROPERTY DAMAGE", "BURGLARY", "VEHICLE THEFT", "FRAUD", "VEHICLE THEFT", 
"FRAUD", "CAR PROWL", "BIKE THEFT", "CAR PROWL", "WARRANT ARREST", 
"STOLEN PROPERTY", "CAR PROWL", "PROPERTY DAMAGE", "VEHICLE THEFT", 
"BIKE THEFT"), occurred.date.or.date.range.start = c("04/17/2015 01:10:00 AM", 
"11/15/2015 12:04:00 PM", "05/29/2015 08:00:00 PM", "12/15/2015 02:25:00 PM", 
"07/28/2015 12:00:00 AM", "02/24/2015 06:01:00 PM", "05/24/2015 04:20:00 PM", 
"03/13/2015 02:04:00 PM", "06/14/2015 08:00:00 AM", "05/19/2015 03:18:00 PM", 
"07/18/2015 06:00:00 AM", "05/11/2015 05:16:00 PM", "01/08/2015 12:52:00 PM", 
"06/17/2015 05:00:00 PM", "07/04/2015 12:00:00 AM", "10/26/2015 12:12:00 AM", 
"05/01/2015 12:00:00 PM", "07/02/2015 10:00:00 PM", "01/10/2015 07:30:00 PM", 
"02/17/2015 01:29:00 PM", "12/17/2015 02:26:00 AM", "08/04/2015 10:49:00 PM", 
"10/27/2015 12:29:00 AM", "07/29/2015 03:00:00 PM", "10/24/2015 06:30:00 PM", 
"02/20/2015 03:07:00 AM", "11/11/2015 09:00:00 AM", "03/24/2015 10:00:00 PM", 
"11/03/2015 08:47:00 PM", "04/15/2015 02:00:00 PM", "07/15/2015 03:00:00 PM", 
"11/17/2015 08:30:00 AM", "09/22/2015 05:00:00 PM", "02/09/2015 09:19:00 AM", 
"01/07/2015 08:30:00 AM", "05/01/2015 07:30:00 AM", "04/26/2015 03:30:00 AM", 
"04/18/2015 03:00:00 AM", "10/01/2015 08:00:00 PM", "05/07/2015 01:00:00 AM", 
"02/05/2015 03:15:00 PM", "01/18/2015 05:00:00 PM", "10/17/2015 11:00:00 PM", 
"03/23/2015 05:35:00 PM", "02/16/2015 07:25:00 PM", "07/30/2015 08:00:00 PM", 
"11/10/2015 02:28:00 PM", "03/14/2015 10:10:00 AM", "12/10/2015 08:26:00 PM", 
"10/05/2015 01:45:00 AM", "02/16/2015 01:56:00 PM", "10/19/2015 06:27:00 PM", 
"12/01/2015 07:30:00 AM", "01/28/2015 08:40:00 PM", "05/01/2015 01:40:00 PM", 
"10/30/2015 03:15:00 AM", "09/04/2015 03:34:00 PM", "06/06/2015 04:53:00 PM", 
"07/22/2015 06:20:00 AM", "12/11/2015 01:41:00 PM", "05/20/2015 01:09:00 PM", 
"09/18/2015 12:00:00 PM", "07/08/2015 11:05:00 PM", "02/22/2015 01:38:00 AM", 
"07/22/2015 01:12:00 PM", "09/07/2015 10:43:00 AM", "08/11/2015 04:00:00 PM", 
"10/13/2015 06:33:00 AM", "10/10/2015 05:32:00 PM", "11/15/2015 07:09:00 PM", 
"11/19/2015 03:05:00 PM", "04/08/2015 04:33:00 PM", "05/11/2015 12:01:00 AM", 
"04/21/2015 06:15:00 PM", "06/13/2015 10:29:00 AM", "06/22/2015 06:41:00 PM", 
"09/03/2015 08:00:00 AM", "04/08/2015 06:00:00 PM", "07/17/2015 08:00:00 PM", 
"08/29/2015 09:00:00 AM", "04/28/2015 01:46:00 PM", "09/07/2015 07:00:00 PM", 
"12/30/2015 06:30:00 AM", "08/29/2015 11:37:00 PM", "08/24/2015 10:00:00 PM", 
"06/17/2015 07:02:00 AM", "02/14/2015 10:21:00 PM", "03/29/2015 07:00:00 PM", 
"10/01/2015 07:15:00 AM", "06/14/2015 03:00:00 PM", "12/16/2014 09:00:00 AM", 
"02/14/2015 07:54:00 PM", "10/02/2015 08:17:00 AM", "05/14/2015 08:30:00 AM", 
"07/07/2015 10:15:00 AM", "04/07/2015 01:48:00 AM", "11/02/2015 11:00:00 PM", 
"04/16/2015 03:00:00 PM", "08/22/2015 08:09:00 AM", "10/24/2015 05:00:00 PM"
)), .Names = c("summarized.offense.description", "occurred.date.or.date.range.start"
), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I use the following code to extract time data from preexisting columns:

```
#Splitting time from column occured.date
SPD_2015 <- mutate(SPD_2015, occurred.time = str_sub(SPD_2015$occurred.date.or.date.range.start, -11, -1))

#Converting character to time for occured.time
SPD_2015$occurred.time <- strptime(SPD_2015$occurred.time, "%I:%M:%S %p") %>%
  str_sub(-8, -1) %>%
  hms()
#creating the occurred.time.hour value so I can isolate the hour value
SPD_2015 <- mutate(SPD_2015, occurred.time.hour = hour(occurred.time))
```

Now I have a column that contains the isolated hour value that a crime occurred, which I can graph using ggplot2.  However, if I subset my data using dplyr:

```
#filtering data for only car prowl
car.prowl <- filter(SPD_2015, summarized.offense.description == "CAR PROWL")
```

The values for time in columns "occurred.time" and "occurred.time.hour" within my newly created dataframe (car.prowl) no longer match.  The "occurred.time.hour" column correctly matches the source but the occurred.time column is now altered.

And just to add to this.  I created a separate dataframe for car prowls because when I originally tried to plot the occurred time of crimes using ggplot

```
ggplot(car.prowl, aes(hour(occurred.time))) +
  geom_bar()
```

I would get the error : "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): x".  Which makes sense and I understand.

```
> dim(car.prowl)
[1] 14  4
```

But car.prowl has a length of 14, and when I enter the following code:

```
> length(hour(car.prowl$occurred.time))
[1] 100
```

It shows the length of the original dataset, instead of the subset length of 14.

Can anyone suggest a solution or a workaround? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Let's first get the output you need for your plotting. We can use `mdy_hms` to convert character to date time. It is probably more robust than your original approach by using `sub_str`. After that, the `hour` can extract the hour based on the date time.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

SPD_2015_updated <- SPD_2015 %>%
  mutate(occurred.time = mdy_hms(occurred.date.or.date.range.start)) %>%
  mutate(occurred.time.hour = hour(occurred.time))

car.prowl_updated <- SPD_2015_updated %>%
  filter(summarized.offense.description == "CAR PROWL")
```

type `glimpse(SPD_2015_updated)` and `glimpse(car.prowl_updated)`. You can see that each record are matched. `occurred.time` is in date time class, while `occurred.time.hour` is in integer class. I think these data frames will be ready for your plotting.

As what went wrong for your original approach, I do not fully understand. But if you type `glimpse(car.prowl)`, you can see that `occurred.time` is in `S4: Period`. This could be the key why `dplyr::filter` was not working. If I have time I will further investigate why `dplyr::filter` cannot subset your original data frame.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Your approach to extracting date/time was definitely more efficient and I am able to plot my original problem.  
I am still slightly confused about what went wrong with my approach, but I guess this is the nature of R until you understand all its little quirks.